# What does facebook auth code for? Why it didn't return the token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I extract the code from the FB OAuth response `AQDiQ1psG13qqcmJgs6-7vHSEzSpnkfbOWWRi8i2zQIexKH3G3h-UPcf9XIW4jdME2hPBEikBmlXspxEOPKZ1AVQrfehh00qsXb3Wul4XHI0nqJOh-W2r7tqXO5epFpetqGg7JVYlSpS4L2BeKae_q1nG_dPKQfoClpMVU3OEHRzo79et231REhwEumpw57IZfxgv95xGkIh-R1U4Ba4Md2D0NqUvTJaLJdaVpYpdRzUYaRl24JklgU_z6AVvLCcdFwsLG36T9qwc4_NGUkHTiLdX82G-tPNEFDETHwTlCC_rDqfgg2fvCbshaRnFwHv-zvxMmUHBOEYmcutpPpwk3oEqcn_ycpgstpzW1UEQU6hFw#_`

by this javascript code

```
   var options = {
            interactive: true,
            url:'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' + this.clientId +
            '&reponse_type=token' +
            '&access_type=online' +
            '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURI(this.redirectUri) +
            '&scope=email'
        }
```

I still can not get the `token` to fetch user's info.

I'm doing this authentication on my developing chrome extension. I also have a backend server. What should I do to fetch the `user's token`?

THanks

Comment: Usually the toke, is saved in the object as a header or some other way that is it hard to access for a user. You can use the returned object to ask for the user information.

Comment: any direction? what method should i use?  the returned callback url only contains the code `AQDiQ1psG13qqcmJgs6-7vHSEzSpnkfbOWWRi8i2zQIexKH3G3h-UPcf9XIW4jdME2hPBEikBmlXspxEOPKZ1AVQrfehh00qsXb3Wul4XHI0nqJOh-W2r7tqXO5epFpetqGg7JVYlSpS4L2BeKae_q1nG_dPKQfoClpMVU3OEHRzo79et231REhwEumpw57IZfxgv95xGkIh-R1U4Ba4Md2D0NqUvTJaLJdaVpYpdRzUYaRl24JklgU_z6AVvLCcdFwsLG36T9qwc4_NGUkHTiLdX82G-tPNEFDETHwTlCC_rDqfgg2fvCbshaRnFwHv-zvxMmUHBOEYmcutpPpwk3oEqcn_ycpgstpzW1UEQU6hFw#_`

Comment: Can you console `response.status` ?

Comment: When I do ` FB.login(function (response) {});` I am getting `response.status` as `connected`.

Comment: Can you also let me know the documentaiton u are following to achive.

Comment: Sure, `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow` . Even i pass the `token` for the response type, it still gives me the `code` instead of token.

Comment: _“by this javascript code”_ – that code does nothing besides creating an object with a few properties and values. So show us the actual code that is interacting with Facebook.